# BCP import exclude identify or some column

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm using BCP because I want to export some columns from a table:

```
bcp "SELECT csusUsageDate, csusType, csusTrack1, csusTrack2, csusTrack3, csusDateReaded, csusLoggedIn FROM [DbJamaica].[dbo].[CS_Usage]" queryout "C:\temp\CS_Usage.txt" /U.. /P.. -c -T
```

Here I exclude my primary key, now I want to import this txt and I want that my primary key will be auto generate:

```
bcp DbJamaica.dbo.CS_Usage out "C:\temp\CS_Usage.txt" /U.. /P.. -c -T
```

I have always format not valid why? I also used format file but I have the same error.
This is my question: how to exclude identify column or some columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, as far as I know. Bcp basically bulk inserts blindly into a table, if the columns don't match, you get an error. What you can do, though, is create a staging table like:

```
SELECT  TOP 0 csusUsageDate, csusType, csusTrack1, csusTrack2, csusTrack3, csusDateReaded, csusLoggedIn
INTO    [DbJamaica].[dbo].[CS_Usage_TEMP] 
FROM    [DbJamaica].[dbo].[CS_Usage]
```

Then you can use bcp on your staging table:

```
bcp DbJamaica.dbo.CS_Usage_TEMP out "C:\temp\CS_Usage.txt" /U.. /P.. -c -T
```

Next you can insert the data from the staging to the actual table, where you set the PK column as `IDENTITY`:

```
INSERT INTO DbJamaica.dbo.CS_Usage (csusUsageDate, csusType, csusTrack1, csusTrack2, csusTrack3, csusDateReaded, csusLoggedIn)
SELECT   csusUsageDate, csusType, csusTrack1, csusTrack2, csusTrack3, csusDateReaded, csusLoggedIn
FROM     DbJamaica.dbo.CS_Usage_TEMP
```

And finally cleanup:

`DROP TABLE DbJamaica.dbo.CS_Usage_TEMP`

Answer (score 0):

Your source file should match the target table structure. Which means, the number of columns in the table should match the number of column in your csv/txt (source file).

In your case, even if your PK column is the identity column you must have the column in the source file. SQL server will take care of identifying the column as identity and it will ignore the values you put there. So you can either have any value or not, your bcp will work.

It's a different use case if you want to retain the identity values. Refer to -E argument in the documentation ([bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15))